# Mixed effects models for a classification task on panel data

Tags: machine-learning, python, binary-classification

I have a problem where I need to make predictions for a binary target $y$ given a set of features $X$ where $X$ is naturally nested in the form of repeated measurements. The data is meant to describe the behavior of people in a game where every line of data $X_t$ is timestamped and represent a behavior at time $t$. A toy example of my data can be the following :

```
ID      session      X1      X2      y
1          1         0.5     a       0
1          2         0.12    b       0
1          3         1.1     d       1
2          1         5.2     c       1
2          2         4.1     a       0
```

I have treated this as a typical classification problem with each sample $X_t$ being an $iid$ and an `XGBoost` classifier yields good enough results. However, many articles online state that this form of panel data (where we find repeated measurements per subject) is better handled with [mixed effect models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model). [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/mixed-effects-random-forests-6ecbb85cb177) excellent blog post goes through mixed effect random forests (MERFs) for a regression problem but says that classification models are yet to be implemented (in $2017$ that is).

To this day, i know of no implementation for MERFs for classification problems. So my question is, did anyone come accross a similar classification task and solved it using mixed effect models? If yes is there any code implementation of such a model? (preferably `python` but I can do with `R` as well to test it).

Answer (score 2):

I am actually looking for something similar, however, in my case I am looking for something to deal with multiclass labeled data.

In my search, I came across GPBoost, which may just satisfy your needs.

https://github.com/fabsig/GPBoost

GPBoost should be both available for Python as well as R, and if I'm correct, binary classification is yet included.